# PostgreSQL extract function in respect to timezones

Tags: postgresql, timezone, extract, sql-timestamp

I use the PostgreSQL `extract` function to pull out month, quarter, year like this:

```
select extract (month from adate) from atable
```

`adate` is a `timestamp with time zone`.

The problem I have is that I find this function completely ambivalent of timezone and I am dealing with a database with data that varies by timezone.  So in some cases I need the result in respect to pacific timezone in other cases I need the result in respect to EST or CST, etc.

Is there a way to get the month/quarter/year of the date in respect to a specific timezone?

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you do is use the `AT TIME ZONE` operator co convert the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` into a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE` and then apply the date_part (AKA extract) operation to that

If you want a specific time zone:

```
  select extract(month from adate AT TIME ZONE 'CST' ) from atable;
```

If you want a specific location: this will follow historical daylight-saving rules (and other statutory time zone changes) for past dates, and assume the current rules for future dates.

```
  select extract(month from adate AT TIME ZONE 'America/Detroit' ) from atable;
```

maybe a used defined function will help with hibernate.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_part_in_zone
     ( part text, instant timestamptz, zone text) 
     returns double precision language sql as 
     'SELECT date_part(part, instant AT TIME ZONE zone)';
```

date_part above is one of the functions behind "extract".

Comment: That is what I am looking for.  Now I have to figure out how to let hibernate let me put that in a HQL query.  It doesn't like it.

Comment: Oh! If you'd mentioned hibernate in the original question I'd have ... run a mile. sorry I can't help with that.

Comment: Your answer still helps, thanks!  Unfortunately hql doesn't allow me to insert the "AT TIME ZONE .." clause in.  Somehow I need to trick hibernate to not interpret it as a hibernate call and just insert that clause in the sql.

Comment: maybe you can write a used defined function?

Comment: From what I can see the only way to do it is call a sql query from hibernate, but you can't do this through HQL.  HQL freaks out about the "AT TIME ZONE" clause and you get a HibernateQueryException.  The problem is I have about 50 complex queries that require the extract with AT TIME ZONE and it would be incredibly trying to do them through straight sql.

Comment: see the function above:  the query to use it doesn not have  `AT TIME ZONE`  - for example `select date_part_in_zone( 'month', '2019-01-01 00:00 +1300', 'America/New_York' );`